# How do I make a sprint velocity graph in Jira using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, graph, jira, metrics

I have a large data set of values (values in column T and dates in column U). I am trying to make it so I can enter the cell number of the first and second date then it adds up the value between those two cells and graphs it on a line graph. The y-axis would be "Sum" and it would just be the sum values between the two dates selected and the x-axis would just be a name for those two dates (i.e: it could be something like "U2-U7") . And then if I wanted to graph more I could enter two more dates and so on. This is the code I have so far that just sums the value between two dates but I don't know how to graph this. Thank you for any assistance!

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalculateTotal()
    Dim startrange As Range
    Dim endrange As Range
    
    
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    
    Dim dateselected As Boolean
    dateselected = False
    'Make sure one date per range is selected
    Do Until dateselected = True
        Set startrange = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Single Cell Starting Date Range (e.x: U5)", , , , , , , 8)
        Set endrange = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Single Cell Ending Date Range (e.x: U8)", , , , , , , 8)
        If IsDate(startrange.Value) And IsDate(endrange.Value) Then
            dateselected = True
        End If
    Loop
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim daterange As Range
        Set daterange = .Range(startrange, endrange) 'Combine Ranges
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim total As Double
        total = 0
        For Each cell In daterange.Offset(0, -1)
            total = total + cell.Value ' Get Total
        Next cell
        MsgBox "Total value of daterange: " & total
    End With
    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 424 ' Add in other cases as needed
            MsgBox "Range selection cancelled, Exiting"
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Unhandled error: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to use [Jira's rest API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/api-group-sprint/#api-agile-1-0-sprint-sprintid-post)

Comment: How exactly would I use that?

Comment: I've never used it for Jira before, I assume it follows standard rest architecture. That link covers it, it's not going to be a super quick thing if you aren't familiar.